# What is the meaning of "I ever do" in ths context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

in this headline:

"Liz Cheney, Front and Center in the Jan. 6 Hearings, Pursues a Mission

“I believe this is the most important thing I’ve ever done professionally,” she said, “and maybe the most important thing I ever do.”"

should it be: "and maybe the most important thing I WILL ever do" instead?
I can understand the: "most important thing I’ve ever" but not ever do I mean

ever done AND will ever do is fine. what is the meaning of ever do in this?

Comment: We often use the simple present for future plans (like *I leave for France tomorrow*), and that might be related to this.

Comment: Speakers often miss words. She meant to say: the most important thing I'll ever do. Also, the automatic software may not have "heard it". On the other hand, it is grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

I believe she is making a personal and a rather emotional statement. The matter means a lot to her on both professional and personal level. The first part relates to the past in the context of her career, while the second part is more about her values in general.

Here, *ever* means *at all* and [is often used in this fashion to intensify the expression](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ever) (see definition #4).

*The most important thing I will ever do* is a similar (and, probably, more commonly used) phrasing which focuses on the future rather than the present.